# Given a path, How do i actually get a file and then readAsDataUrl using Cordova File API?

Tags: cordova, file-upload, cordova-plugins

I am completely lost. Following the example i cannot tell if i am supposed to pass a path or some file object?

```
var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = function(e){
        alert(e.target.result);
    };
reader.readAsDataURL(file);
```

What should "file" be? If it's some type of object can someone show me how to create one of those given the path of the file? I am trying to take a picture using this https://github.com/mbppower/CordovaCameraPreview and then upload the result. when i take the picture i am returned a full path to the file which can be used as a src for an image element and is confirmed working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realize it's an old question but I found it helpful, so if anyone else needs help here's how to do it (with `Promises`):

Given you've installed `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file`…

Use this function:

```
function filePathToDataUrl(filePath) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(filePath, function (fileEntry) {
            fileEntry.file(function (file) {
                var reader = new window.FileReader();
                reader.onloadend = function() {
                  resolve(reader.result);
                };
                reader.readAsDataURL(file);
            }, function (fileEntryError) { reject('fileEntry.file error:' + JSON.stringify(fileEntryError, 0, 2)); });
        }, function (resolveFSError) { reject('resolveLocalFileSystemURL error:' + JSON.stringify(resolveFSError, 0, 2)); });
    });
}
```

Now you can do `filePathToDataUrl(absFilePath).then(dataUrl => {…}).catch(console.error)`!

Answer (score 0):

If you have a path, you can use `resolveLocalFileSystemURL` to get a [FileEntry](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileEntry#File) object, which you can then copy or move.

You can also get access to the [File](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) object with something like:

```
resolveLocalFileSystemURL('assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=711B4C9D-97D6-455A-BC43-C73059A5C3E8&ext=JPG', function(fileEntry) {
    fileEntry.file(function(file) {
        var reader = new FileReader(),
            data = null;
        reader.onloadend = function(event) {
            data = reader.result;
        };
        console.log('Reading file: ' + file.name);
        reader.readAsDataURL(file)
    });
});
```